# is it possible to track "Add to cart" event without using google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have already try to track Add to cart Button using Google tag manager.

But I want to do it without using google tag manager.

i don't know it's possible or not.if you guys have any suggest let me know

thank's

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom tracking event to do that. How is that possible? First of all you should have the analytics js library loaded in the page. It matters if this is done through GTM or by putting the GA snippet yourself.
If you put the analytics.js in the page without using GTM, you can add an onClick event on your add to cart button. When this button is clicked you can call the function like below

```
ga('send', 'event', eventCategory, eventAction, eventLabel, eventValue);
```

The variables eventCategory, eventAction, eventLabel, eventValue will be strings that represent how you want to see this event reported in GA.
The second case that the analytics.js library is loaded through GTM is kinda trickier. That is because gtm uses a different tracker for each tag fired. What you have to do is find the correct one to send your event. To find the correct tracker either you can [implement a named tracker](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/01/21/gtm-existing-tracking/) on the page or call the function

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  // Logs the tracker created above to the console.
  console.log(tracker);
});
```

To get the tracker name. All the parameters will depend on the context of what you want to do but I think you can move on with this info.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, obviously, since click tracking precedes Google Tag Manager. However you would need to add a bit of javascript code to your page.

If your button looks like this:

```
<button type="button">Add to Cart</button>
```

then the simplest way would be to add an onclick event handler to the button. An "event handler" is a way to execute Javascript in response to a user action - and despite a similar name it is not related to Google Analytics events, which is what you would use to send the data to Google Analytics:

```
   <button onclick="ga('send', 'event', {'eventCategory':'button', 'eventAction':'add2Cart','transport':'beacon'})" type="button">Add to Cart</button>
```

The data should show up in the behavior section of your Google Analytics Account in the "events" section. Event Category and Action are mandatory, optionally you might specify a label and a value (where value is an integer and is used to monetize relevant actions that are not sales).

I assume your add to cart button navigates away from the current page, so it might be a good idea to specify beacon as the transport method. This makes it more likely that your data is being sent away before the page unloads. Other than that the syntax suggested by IgneeI64 is just as valid.

Again, you have two types of event here that should not be confused, a JavaScript event which is a feature of the programming language, and the Google Analytics event which is a convention on how to store data that is not an actual pageview.